# How to append cell values in openpyxl directly

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to append cell value using openpyxl, by appending the value directly.

this works:

```
wb1=load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws1=wb1.active

testlist=('two','three','four','five')

for i in testlist:
    ws1['A1'].value = ws1['A1'].value +(' ') + i

print(ws1['A1'].value)
```

A1 has a value of "one", after the loop runs it has "one two three four five"

But is it possible to use the append method directly on the cell value?

```
for i in testlist:
        ws1.append['A1'].value = i
```

however this throws an error
"TypeError: 'method' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: What do you want to do? Insert a row at A1 with the cells being 'one','two','three','four','five'?

Comment: @GordonAitchJay I'm trying to add the data "one, two, three, four, five" as one value into cell A1.

Comment: I realized the solutions isn't achievable the way i wanted as the cell values can't be appended directly using the append method on the cell itself. We have to assign it to a list, then append the list and read it back to the cell, overwriting the existing data. I marked @Redox answer as a solution, while achieves the same as my first code, its more efficient and elegant.

Comment: The documentation states that `ws.append()` is for appending rows. If you don't want to do that, why are you using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to move the tuple into a string and can add it to cell `A1` like this.

```
wb1=Workbook()
ws1=wb1.active

testlist=('one','two','three','four','five')
myString = ' '.join(map(str, testlist))
myString.strip()
ws1['A1'].value = myString

wb1.save('test1.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2):

The error  "method' object is not subscriptable" means that, you are treating an object as python `dict` or `dict` like object which the object isn't. Because the `append` method returns None.
As per documentation of openpyxl, You can [worksheet.append](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.append) via:

1. **A list**: all values are added in order, starting from the first column.
   which is your case. simply doing the following should work:

```py
wb1=Workbook()
ws1=wb1.active

testlist=('one','two','three','four','five')

# append each element side by side in a single row
ws1.append(testlist)

# To append each element vertical direction in new row you can un-comment next 2 lines.

#for entry in testlist:
#    ws1.append([entry])


wb1.save('test.xlsx')
```

2. **A dict**: values are assigned to the columns indicated by the keys (numbers or letters). This might help if you are targeting a specific column.

**Or**
 To have more control simply use [worksheet.cell](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.cell).